# Datatables column width increases automatically when paginated

Tags: jquery, datatables

I've three datatables on my page, with pagination option. The data on the tables are loaded through `ajax`. Everything is perfect before doing any actions on the tables. If I paginate the table then the size of the table increases automatically. This is my code:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/get/data',
        success: function (resp) {

            let str = '';
            for (let j = 1; j < resp.length; j++) {
                str += `<tr>
                                <td>${moment(resp[j].purchase_date).format('MM-DD-YYYY')}</td>
                                <td>${resp[j].items}</td>
                            </tr>\n`;
            }
            $("#table1 tbody").html(str);
            initDataTable();
        }
    });


    function initDataTable() {
            $('#table1').DataTable({
                "scrollY": 250,
                "scrollX": false,
                "pagingType": "full",
                "autoWidth": false,
                "pageLength": 10,
                bFilter: false,
                bInfo: false,
                aoColumnDefs: [
                    {
                        bSortable: false,
                        aTargets: [-1]
                    }
                ]
            });
        }
```

This is the CSS for the data table.

```
#table1, #table2, #table3 {
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100% !important;
}

.dataTables_wrapper {
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 8px;
    padding:0 30px 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.dataTables_wrapper table.dataTable thead .sorting {
    background: url(../img/sort_both.png) no-repeat center right!important
}

.dataTables_wrapper table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc {
    background-image: url(../img/sort_asc.png)!important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat!important
}

.dataTables_wrapper table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc {
    background-image: url(../img/sort_desc.png)!important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat!important
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default `Datatable` applies smart width to all column via default `sWidth` property as given in [documentation](https://legacy.datatables.net/usage/columns) . You can modify it for a particular column in the `aoColumnDefsaoColumnDefs` property.

Comment: This is not working for me. I tried both `aoColumnDefs` and `aoColumns`. But the issue persists.